# Bokeh: Images for hovertool doen't show

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I tried to show the images when the mouse hover the graph, but it never shows the images.

Here is a part of my code.

```
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        x=,
        y=,
        imgs=icon_data))
```

The url of each icon is contained in the icon_data.

```
    tooltips = """
<div>
    <div>
        <img
            scr="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
            border="2"
        ></img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><span>@x{%m/%d %p%I}</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
"""
hover_format = {'x' : 'datetime'}
return HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, formatters=hover_format, mode='vline')
```

Here is the function to return hovertool.
And the graph shows like this

[The hover window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtBnU.png)

Anyone who knows the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all glpyhs support hit testing, and hence not all glyphs support hover tooltips. As of Bokeh `0.12.14`, the `Image` glyph is one of the glyphs that does not support it. However, one of the core developers is currently working on adding this capability.